# AUTH_FAILED OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, ics-openvpn, openvpn-connect

I have been OpenVPN client for about 2 years and now when I'm trying to connect it says that,

2022-03-21 13:14:13 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED

2022-03-21 13:14:13 SIGUSR1[soft,auth-failure] received, process restarting

2022-03-21 13:14:16 SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting

There's no any username passwords used by me for login it was a auto validation.

Please help me to fix this issue soon.

Comment: Contact the server owner/provider